# How do I find the cmdlets in a given module (loaded from file)

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, import-module

I have a C# DLL full of PowerShell cmdlets, and I want to know how to retrieve the list of cmdlets from a PowerShell prompt. I've tried:

```
Import-Module .\psconfig.dll
Get-Command -Name psconfig
```

But that doesn't work. (the import works, but not the `Get-Command`)

What's the proper way to do this, so that I get a list of only the cmdlets included in my DLL?

Comment: Get-Command -Module some module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Command -Name psconfig` is looking for a cmdlet named `psconfig`. To get a list of the cmdlets imported from `psconfig.dll` you need to list the imported cmdlets for that module:

```
Get-Command -ListImported -Module psconfig
```

or just

```
Get-Command -Module psconfig
```

Comment: never played with "true" cmdlets -- C#, not powershell. i guess a dll module doesnt require a psd1?

Comment: @JaquelineVanek Script modules don't require a module manifest either. It's just good practice to have one.